# I need help writing Geometric series in c++

Tags: c++

Hello guys this question is part my assignment Can someone explain how do I test for n and A from 1 to 5 (25 rows total). I'm little confused here.
Thanks!

```
//Geometric Series
//Test for values of n from 1 to 5 and A from 1 to 5 (25 rows total).
//N
//∑Ai = A1 + A2 + A3 +...+ AN
//i =1
//Iterative code solution:
 int term, sum = 0;
 for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
     term = A;
     for(int j = 1; j < i; j++)
          term = term * A;
     sum = sum + term;
}
return sum;
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by test in this context?

Comment: Test means put in the values in the function and test them and see what are the results.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? You essentially have a function that does something, and you want to know how to put the values in the function? Can you clarify?

Comment: I want to know how can I test values or how can I put the values in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking about specifiying arguments. Simply put, in a function's declaration, you can specify arguments passed to it, ie

```
int foo(int bar) {
    return bar;
}
```

In your case, assuming the code you provided is correct, you'd simply have

```
int foo(int A, int n) {
    int term, sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        term = A;
         for(int j = 1; j < i; j++)
              term = term * A;
         sum = sum + term;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You can then later call foo, by passing in A and n; ie

```
auto out = foo(3,2);
```

Where a = 3, and n = 2.

Comment: Thanks for helping!